# Off logic with Pi and Picamera using GPIO

Tags: gpio, python, camera

Just trying to customize some Picamera functionality though this is my first time coding in Python. Basically I am using the GPIO with a button switch to essentially turn just the preview on and off.  Ideally i did not want to use wait_for_edge because I wanted the pi to do other stuff in the interim and not be locked up waiting for the button press.   Then I submitted to using it after the event detection I set up since its fine that the program waits while in preview mode (for this case).

The issue comes with just trying to use one button.  I basically initiate event detection on the button, then remove it once preview mode starts. Then I set it up to wait for the button press again.  But I run into:

```
RuntimeError: Conflicting edge detection already enabled for this GPIO channel
```

The following is meat of the code thus far:

```
from time import sleep
import picamera
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import datetime

today = datetime.datetime.today()
captureOn = 25


GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setup(captureOn, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP)
startPrev = True


def preview(channel):

        global captureOn
        global startPrev

        if GPIO.input(captureOn):
            print ("Rising Edge detected")
            sleep(.5)
        else:

            if (startPrev == True):

                with picamera.PiCamera() as camera:
                    camera.resolution = 1920, 1080
                    camera.framerate = 30
                    camera.rotation = 0
                    camera.brightness = 50
                    camera.start_preview()
                    while True:
                          sleep(1)
                          print('preview started')
                          startPrev = False
                          if GPIO.input(captureOn):
                                 break

            else:
                ...stop preview code?


                print('stop preview')




GPIO.add_event_detect(captureOn, GPIO.BOTH, callback=preview, bouncetime=1000)
```

EDIT: It seems that while in my IF statement, the GPIO event detection is disabled or not being called as pressing the button does nothing (no print outs either)
FIXED: partially due to a wiring issue but added some code in the  while statement above!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I highly suggest for practicality you eliminate the falling and rising reinstating altogether by using `GPIO.BOTH` as shown [here](http://raspi.tv/2014/rpi-gpio-update-and-detecting-both-rising-and-falling-edges).  You would use `GPIO.add_event_detect(25, GPIO.BOTH, callback=my_callback)` and then check the input like so:

```
GPIO.setup(25, GPIO.IN) 
def my_callback(channel):
    if GPIO.input(25):     # if port 25 == 1
        print "Rising edge detected on 25"
    else:                  # if port 25 != 1
        print "Falling edge detected on 25"

# when a changing edge is detected on port 25, regardless of whatever 
# else is happening in the program, the function my_callback will be run
GPIO.add_event_detect(25, GPIO.BOTH, callback=my_callback)
```

Of course, you would replace the "print" lines with the turn on and off preview code. This link above contains a whole tutorial on the topic. Hope that helps!

**EDIT:** To print a different statement each time the button is pressed and switch between statement a and b use this code(its in c++ because I am more familiar with it, but you could convert it to Python quickly.):

```
bool printb = 0;

if(printb = 0)
{
  println(a);
  printb = 1;
}
else
{
 println(b);
 printb = 0;
}
```

Comment: Ah, that link was totally what I was looking for.  I had implemented GPIO.BOTH before but the program kept turning the preview on and off incrementally even though no action had been taken.  Thanks for the info.

Comment: Actually now I am a little curious.   Using a typical push button, the above code would print "Rising..." on the pressing action and then print "Falling..." when the button comes up, all in one motion correct?  What if I wanted an initial press (full action of rising and falling) to print(a) and a subsequent press (again, full action) to print(b).  Then the next press would print(a) and the next would  print(b) and so on?

Comment: You could use some Boolean logic. Make a variable called `printb` and set it to `0`. Then in my function above, in the else part, add an if clause(c++ version): `if(printb = 0){println(a);printb=1}else{println(b);printb=0}` This way it the code keeps track of what to print and only prints the line after the rise and fall.

Comment: See my revised answer for better format.

Comment: Null, so I get it to work using the print statements, but now the only issue I am having is placement of the camera init code and the start_preview/stop_preview functions.   I've moved them all over the place and seem to have it working when all if i is in the if statement above.  Only issue is that after I start_preview (followed by sleep) the preview shuts off after the sleep time.  Edited what I have in above.

Comment: Fixed due to a wiring issue of the button.  But the code works.